# How to pattern match against absurd / unconstructable Type?

Tags: agda

From what I understand these two definitions a̶r̶e̶ ̶e̶q̶u̶i̶v̶a̶l̶e̶n̶t̶ represent the same behaviour:

```
data _<_ : ℕ → ℕ → Set where                       
    lt-zero : {n : ℕ} → zero < suc n
    lt-suc  : {m n : ℕ} → m < n → (suc m) < (suc n)

lt : ℕ → ℕ → Bool
lt  _       zero   = false
lt  zero   (suc n) = true
lt (suc m) (suc n) = m < n
```

Except that `_<_` can be more easily used to prove things about itself, and `lt`, from what I have found, is easier to use for programming other behaviours. For example I can see how I can easily define a `min` function using `lt`:

```
min : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ
min x y where lt x y
... | true  = x
... | false = y
```

Is there a way for me to define `min` and other similar functions using `_<_`? From what I have found there is no way to pattern match `x < y` if `y` is less than `x`. Is there a different method to use `_<_` in these cases?

EDIT: Would adding a not-true case to `_<_` be a sensible idea?

̶E̶D̶I̶T̶ ̶2̶:̶ ̶O̶r̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶'̶c̶o̶r̶r̶e̶c̶t̶'̶ ̶w̶a̶y̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶i̶t̶?̶

EDIT 3: I have changed the below definition of min, in order to be able to omit proofs for `x <? y` when using `min`.

```
data _<?_ (n m : ℕ) : Set where
    isLT  : n < m → n <? m
    notLT : m ≤ n → n <? m

min : (x y : ℕ) → {p : x <? y} → ℕ
min x y (isLT _)  = x
min x y (notLT _) = y
```

This did not work as expected. If I true to evaluate `min 1 2`, using C-c C-n, it returns `min 1 2`. I can get it to return the min, if I give it a proof, however if I evaluate `min 2 1 (isLT _)` it returns 2, instead of giving me an error message. Is there a way for me to define `min` using `_<_`, so that Agda could evaluate `min 1 2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to eliminate impossible patterns in Agda. Using your definition of `_<_`
you can try to prove transitivity to illustrate this.

```
le-trans : ∀ {m n k} → m < n → n < k → m < k
le-trans {k = k} lt-zero b = {!!}
le-trans (lt-suc a) (lt-suc b) = lt-suc (le-trans a b)

Goal: 0 < k
b  : suc .n < k
```

We pattern match on the first argument, the step case is a simple application of the hypothesis. In the base case, we have to pattern match on `k` since the base constructor of your data type says `zero < suc n`, but we don't know anything about `k` yet. Upon pattern matching on `k` we see two cases

```
le-trans : ∀ {m n k} → m < n → n < k → m < k
le-trans {k = zero} lt-zero b = {!!}
le-trans {k = suc k} lt-zero b = {!!}
le-trans (lt-suc a) (lt-suc b) = lt-suc (le-trans a b)
```

In the first one, we see something impossible, i.e, `Goal: 0 < zero` and we have an element of type `b  : suc .n < zero`, which cannot occur. Then, you can pattern match on `b` and Agda will see that you cannot construct such thing and will eliminate this case `le-trans {k = zero} lt-zero ()`. Whereas in the other case, you can prove it with the base constructor.

```
le-trans : ∀ {m n k} → m < n → n < k → m < k
le-trans {k = zero} lt-zero ()
le-trans {k = suc k} lt-zero b = lt-zero
le-trans (lt-suc a) (lt-suc b) = lt-suc (le-trans a b)
```

Therefore, defining a not-true case in datatypes is not appropriate. You define how elements are constructed. Your last definition of `_<?_` makes sense and can be, in fact, used.

Edit on `min`

Once you have the inductive relation for `_<?_`, you can work as follows.  Define a function that gives you `m <? n` and then for the `min` function, do a with abstraction calling that function.

```
data _≥_ : ℕ → ℕ → Set where
  get-z : ∀ {n} → n ≥ zero
  get-s : ∀ {m n} → m ≥ n → (suc m) ≥ (suc n)

data _<?_ (n m : ℕ) : Set where
  y-< : n < m → n <? m
  n-< : n ≥ m → n <? m

f<? : (m n : ℕ) → m <? n
f<? zero zero = n-< get-z
f<? zero (suc n) = y-< lt-zero
f<? (suc m) zero = n-< get-z
f<? (suc m) (suc n) with f<? m n
f<? (suc m) (suc n) | y-< x = y-< (lt-suc x)
f<? (suc m) (suc n) | n-< x = n-< (get-s x)

min : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ
min x y with f<? x y
min x y | y-< _ = x
min x y | n-< _ = y
```

Comment: Thank you, I understood what you said, but I still don't understand how I could use `_<_` to define a min function properly. See edit 3 for my clarification.

Comment: @JacobWard I added a new part on how to use `_<_` to implement `min`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. Is the reason I was getting the weird behaviour I described in EDIT 3 because I didn't explicitly define proofs like you did with f<?

Comment: The reason it was returning 2 is because it was just matching the first case of your definition `min x y (isLT _)  = x` where `x` is `2` and `y` is `1`. It was ill-defined and so you could do anything with it.